# Why do I need to renew my IP address every time I start my computer before I can get internet access?

Tags: windows-10, internet, ip-address

I have a very weird problem that has just popped up out of the blue. When I start my Windows 10 machine I don't immediately have access to the internet. I can connect the the router but I have no access to the internet. After doing some poking around I found that the command `ipconfig /renew` can be used to reset the default ip address (I think that's what its doing anyway) and that this fixes my problem. However I need to go through this every time I start my machine. Does anybody know why and more importantly how to fix my this permanently? Thanks

Comment: Are you using third-party firewall and antivirus, or are you just using Windows Defender?

Comment: `ipconfig /renew` tries to get a new DHCP lease. It doesn't have anything to do with your actual internet connection. Do you see an active connection on the router as soon as you login? Otherwise it might just take time for it to establish a connection.

Comment: Hi Seth, Yes I get an active and strong connection to the router as soon as I log in but this connection doesn't have internet access until I use `ipconfig /renew`. Other devises still connect and work fine. Also, I am not using any anti virus other than what's native to windows.

Comment: @user3059024 - Please use the edit functionality to update your question instead of using comments to provide additional information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> After doing some poking around I found that the command ipconfig
> /renew can be used to reset the default ip address (I think that's
> what its doing anyway) and that this fixes my problem.

You are currently using Windows 10 build 14393.479 after last week's [KB3201845](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB3201845).

> Does anybody know why and more importantly how to fix my this
> permanently?

You need to update to Windows 10 build 14393.576 by installing [KB3206632](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB3206632).

It has been confirmed by Microsoft that the KB3201845 caused the problem you describe.

> If the service is broken or behaving unexpectedly, customers are
> unable to access the internet or local network resources, which
> appears to be the behavior that some Windows 10 customers are
> experiencing after the update.
>
> A spokesperson for Microsoft said they are aware of the issue and gave
> the following advice;

> > **"Some customers using Windows 10 have reported difficulties connecting
> > to the internet, as a first step, we recommend customers restart their
> > PCs." "If this does not resolve the problem, visit our website for
> > further support."**

The release notes for KB3206632 state the following; **"Addressed a service crash in CDPSVC that in some situations could lead to the machine not being able to acquire an IP address."**

[Microsoft breaks DHCP with Windows 10 update; suggests a reboot to get back online](https://www.neowin.net/news/microsoft-breaks-dhcp-with-latest-windows-10-update-suggests-a-reboot-to-get-back-online)

You can confirm you are affected by this bug by verifying you have been assigned a 169.254.0.0/16 ip address.

> Have a look at reserved IP address [RFC 5735](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5735) under special use IPv4:

> 169.254.0.0/16 - This is the "link local" block.  As described in
> [RFC3927](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5735), it is allocated for communication between hosts on a
> single link.  Hosts obtain these addresses by auto-configuration,
> such as when a DHCP server cannot be found.

[Why is Windows' default IP address 169.xx.xx.xx?](https://superuser.com/questions/238625/why-is-windows-default-ip-address-169-xx-xx-xx)

Comment: For more specifics on how to solve the dhcp problem long enough to install the update follow the instructions located here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10741/windows-10-fix-network-connection-issues