# So Microsoft killed DHCP with a Win10 software update. How to fix it?

Tags: dhcp, auto-updates

http://arstechnica.com/business/2016/12/microsoft-windows-10-dhcp-broken-update/

Excerpt:

### Microsoft has quietly fixed a software update it released last week,

### which effectively prevented Windows 10 users from connecting to the

### Internet or joining a local network.

So Microsoft broke the DHCP client on Windows 10 computers.  But now they say they have a patch to fix it.

My question is:  How do you get the update if you can't get online?

Certainly, my 92 year old grandmother wouldn't know to set up static IP, for instance.  All she would know is that it quit connecting, suddenly.  She might not even try again for a week.

-->  This is not a duplicate, because you can't renew an IP address if DHCP isn't functioning.  The non-technical user is simply stuck.  It simply cannot connect - it never gets an address or gateway.

Gram is not a computer scientist, so would be more inclined to take it back to the store than to call me.

### --EDIT:  In the end I didn't see any more headlines about this issue. So I guess granny was all right after all, even if she needed help.

Comment: You could download the fix from another computer, install the fix to a USB drive, and then install it from there. You could also uninstall the KB that broke it and then update again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I need to renew my IP address every time I start my computer before I can get internet access?](http://superuser.com/questions/1156739/why-do-i-need-to-renew-my-ip-address-every-time-i-start-my-computer-before-i-can)

Comment: The article you linked to provided the solution, restarting is enough to fix this problem long enough to install the update

Comment: This post had nothing to do with renewing DHCP addresses; it was about the lack of getting one in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions:

1. Configure a static IP address, DNS servers, and gateway.
2. Rebooting, resetting your winsock catalog, and rebooting again fixes the problem temporarily, getting you online long enough to deploy the fix. At least this worked for two machines that had this issue that I tested it on.

Comment: Accepted because you are absolutely correct about the procedure.  And I didn't see any more headlines about poor old granny.  ;-)