# Windows 10 DHCP stopped working properly and I can't restart it

Tags: networking, windows-10, dhcp

For some reason Windows DHCP service, for both IPv4 and IPv6, bugged by itself in one of my laptops, because the network adaptors can't receive correct settings anymore. My internet gateway IP is **192.168.1.254**, however both wireless and Ethernet adaptors are receiving **169.254.1.x** local IP and **255.255.0.0** subnet mask, when the proper addresses should be **192.168.1.x** and **255.255.255.0** respectively.

As expected, when I set a static local IP on both network interface cards, connectivity is restored. The other Windows machines and smartphones in the network are assigned IPs fine, meaning my internet modem DHCP is working properly. I can't recall when this issue began, I believe it was a couple of days ago, probably after a Windows update (now running build 18363.816).

And now comes the actual issue: I found in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1090319/windows-10-not-getting-ip-address-from-dhcp) thread that the solution is restarting the DHCP Client service on a elevated command prompt:

```
net stop dhcp
net start dhcp
```

However, even in adminstrative prompt, I get this error, which seems to be caused by the lack of appropriate permission:

```
System error 5 has occurred.
Access is denied.
```

I get the same error when attempting to stop or restart DHCP Client service on Services console. I searched everywhere on how to get permission to restart this service, and one source instructed to add NETWORK SERVICE entity to DHCP Client security settings and granting it Full Control permission, but the error persisted.

Also uninstalled drivers for both wired and wireless adaptors, but still no luck, as the issue is caused by a broken Windows service. I'm short of doing a refresh install, because I just can't find a solution to this issue. I know I can always fix static local IPs, but I would like Windows DHCP to work again.

Comment: Try a Windows 10 Repair Install.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button, select Run.  See if that fixes your networking before doing a fresh install

Comment: "169.254.1.:" is when windows cannot negotiate an address from the router https://packetlife.net/blog/2008/sep/24/169-254-0-0-addresses-explained/, Try a winsock reset and reboot, from an admin command promt type: netsh winsock reset

Comment: I think when the wireless (and wired) drivers are reinstalled that will do the same thing. I thought the same as you did, but I read that the drivers were reinstall. Let's see.

Comment: The error you received is an error to permissions, verify you are an administrator on the computer

Comment: Similar question here>>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/1106931/network-devices-getting-an-ip-address-in-the-169-254-x-x-range

Comment: @Moab 's suggestion worked, thank you very much! Thanks for the article link as well, I appreciate it.